# Changing the size of the box by the user

Tags: scripting, objects

I want to create a box, export it using Blend4Web to html and post it on the site. And so that the site visitor chooses the width, height and depth of the box. I need these parameters to be changeable. Is this possible in a blender?

Comment: Blend4Web appears to be a third-party version of Blender so you should ask the developers of it if what you want to do is possible.